# What is the best way to compare 2 arrays and echo out the values of the same content of the array in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to compare 2 arrays in a menu. I set an default array to my acl menu and i make array for users to access the menu. So I am basically trying to compare the default menu array [array 1] to user's assigned menu array [array 2]. Now I want to show only the same object inside 2 arrays.

I have here in array 1

```html
 $this->data['menus'] = array(
            '1' => array(
                'Dashboard' => '/LMS/Dashboard',
            ),
            '2' => array(
                'Notifications' => '/LMS/Notifications',
            ),
            '3' => array(
                'Clients' => '/LMS/Clients',
            ),
            '4' => array(
                'Penalties' => '/LMS/Penalties',
            ),
            '5' => array(
                'Payments' => '/LMS/Payments',
            ),
            '6' => array(
                'Profit' => '/LMS/Profit',
            ),
            '7' => array(
                'Income' => '/LMS/Income',
            ),
            '8' => array(
                'Outcome' => '/LMS/Outcome',
            ),
            '9' => array(
                'Accounts' => '/LMS/Accounts',
            )
        );
```

And in array 2

```html
Array ( [pages_id] => 
  Array ( 
   [0] => 1 
   [1] => 2 
   [2] => 3 
   [3] => 4 
   [4] => 8 
   [5] => 9 
        )
  ) 1
```

If you can see the numbers 1-9. that is basically I am trying to compare.

By default I'm doing the output by this code

```html
foreach($menus as $key => $val) {
        foreach($val as $k => $v) {
            ?>
             <li class="nav-item <?=$active?>">
               <a class=" nav-link <?=$active?> " href="<?=$v?>"> 
                 <?=$icon?><?=$k?>
               </a>
             </li>
            <?php
          }
       }
```

it works fine to show all the menu. But what i want is to show only what the user can access which is why i try to compare the menu array to the array 2.

Comment: you can try to foreach the array 2 inside the menu foreach. this will work but not the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`array_intersect_key`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) on the menus array and the flipped (to make the values the keys) access array:

```
$pages = array_intersect_key($menus, array_flip($access['pages_id']));
```

You could then iterate over the `$pages` variable in the same way as you are currently iterating over the `$menus` array.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/MVFER)

Comment: how can I convert the array 2 in the format given in demo?

Comment: @ArvinJasonCabrera the format given in the demo is the same as in your question. See this updated demo which does a `print_r($access)` and you'll see they're the same. https://3v4l.org/OVRhG

Comment: oh Im so sorry @Nick. yeah it really works. I'm sorry to bother you.

Comment: @ArvinJasonCabrera no problem at all. You need to be happy with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think using

1. array_intersect
2. array_diff